# Intellij IDEA typeface

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, fonts, typeface, jetbrains-ide

Which typeface has been used in this picture?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please read how to ask questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the code editor window? That's the default font for the IntelliJ suite, [Menlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menlo_(typeface)) by Jim Lyles.

You can download it for free at [Cufon](http://www.cufonfonts.com/it/font/13494/menlo)

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks!